# Concurrency Issue Grails

Tags: grails, datasource, grails-orm

I am using this code for updating a row.

```
SequenceNumber.withNewSession  {
   def hibSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
   Sql sql = new Sql(hibSession.connection())
   def rows = sql.rows("select for update query");
}
```

in this query I am updating the number initially sequenceNumber is 1200.
and every time this code run then it will b increamented by 1.
and I am running this code 5 times in loop.
but this is not flushing the hibernate session so that every time I am getting the same number 1201.

I have also used

```
hibSession.clear()
hibSession.flush()
```

but no success.

If I use following code then its works fine.

```
SequenceNumber.withNewSession  {
   Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
   def rows = sql.rows("select for update query")
}
```

every time I am getting a new number.

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with Transaction, + flush it on the end, like:

```
SequenceNumber.withTransaction { TransactionStatus status ->
    ...
    status.flush()
}
```

Comment: I have used this with 
hibSession.clear()
hibSession.flush()
status.flush()
Now its working.
Thanks